# What's the difference between data declaration?

Tags: nuxt.js

In nuxt, when we want some data in a page, we would use:

```
data () {
  return {
    dialog: false
  }
}
```

However, the syntax is different for components:

```
data: () => ({
  dialog: false,
})
```

The syntax used for pages does not work for components.

Why is the change necessary here?

Are there any differences in behavior I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The binding context is different. Arrow functions do not have their own this. See: [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)